# object reference not set to an instance of an object error in C#

Tags: c#, smartcard

I am programming a smartcard system using C#. In my unpublished program, it don't show any errors and running smoothly.

But when I converted it into an installer and run it's exe file it shows an error `object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Any idea why does this happened in an exe file?

Comment: You're suggesting it's running on your debug, but failing after install? how did you convert it?

Comment: Do you have the stack trace or any logs for the error. This question comes up many times a day. Really what it means is that you are trying to access an object that hasn't been set.

Comment: @Noctis it is the same I think. The exe file in the debug and the installed one. If I clicked the exe rather than the run button in visual studio I get an error.

Comment: have a look at what @Nico said ...

Comment: @Nico I got confused already because in my source code it does not show any errors. It shows null in some of my objects.

Comment: some times it works in debug mode and if you run exe it fails .you can not depend on debug mode as it allows to execute your program even there are some run time issues, share your code.

Comment: @LucasJuan, please, PLEASE write your own answer explaining how you solved your problem. Think of the kids, I mean future visitors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help you locate the problem you can idetify where in the code this is happening by catching all unhandled exceptions and logging them in a manor that is fit for your application.

Now each application type has different methods for catching unhandled exceptions. Here are some basic pointers for different types.

WinForms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

WPF : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx

WebForms \ MVC : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx

Now how you log is your own responsibility you can use some off the shelf \ OS features if you wish.

log4net: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

EventLogs: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024

Back to original problem. The reason you are getting the error is you are accessing \ manipulating an object that is not set. Now which object and why is quite difficult to trace and impossible for us to resolve without some indication as to where this error is ocurring. At a minimum we would need to know where in the code this is happening.

Ideally a full stack trace will resolve this quite quickly.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I would have some reference in the future.